# Changing the 'multiple' property of a select based on another select

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I am building an Angular app, wherein I have two dropdowns. If the first dropdown is selected is 'Angular', multi-select should be enabled for the second dropdown. Below are the relevant files:

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Topic</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="topic">
        <mat-option value="ang" (click)="onTopicClick()">Angular</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="vue" (click)="onTopicClick()">Vue</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<br>
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Version</mat-label>
    <mat-select [multiple]="multiEnabled">
        <mat-option value="1">1</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="2">2</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  //styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  //Inline css
  styles: [`
    h2{
      color: green
    }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'first-app';
  topic = "";
  multiEnabled = false;
  onTopicClick(){
    if(this.topic === "ang"){
      this.multiEnabled = true
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to implement the above code, I get an error in console stating that *core.js:6157 ERROR Error: Cannot change `multiple` mode of select after initialization.*

Is there a way that I can implement this feature? Or a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

`multiple` property of mat-select can't change dynamically just you can initialize it not change it after initialize.

So basically you can use *ngIf for the dropdown to show it based on your first dropdown selection.

You can refer this question here for your error:
[Error: Cannot change `multiple` mode of select after initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204450/error-cannot-change-multiple-mode-of-select-after-initialization)

Answer (score 1):

Try having your function on the select instead of on the option.

html:

```
<select 
     [(ngModel)]="topic"
     (change)='onTopicClick($event)'>
   <option 
     class='option' 
     [value]="Angular">
         Angular
   </option>
   <option 
     class='option' 
     [value]="Vue">
         Vue
   </option>
</select>
```

component.ts:

```
public onTopicClick(event) {
   title = event.target.value;
   this.topic = value;
   console.log(value);
}
```

For your second select, you could use an *ngif statement to decide if you are going to show it for not.

```
<mat-form-field
    *ngIf="title === 'Angular'">
```

Comment: Hi Catherine. Thanks for your response. I have to show the second select at all times, its just that I need to be able to toggle the multi-select on dropdown.

Comment: Are you waiting to change the content in the second dropdown due to the first dropdown value?

Comment: Not the content, the 'multiple' property. In <mat-select [multiple]="multiEnabled"> HTML code line, multiEnabled is initially set to false. If 'Angular' is selected in the first dropdown, it is to be set as true, hence enabling multi select. I was able to set the variable to true, but it is throwing up the error mentioned in the question. Was wondering if we have some workaround for this.

Comment: I don't think you can select multiple options in a select. I think you might be after checkboxes.

Comment: Yup we can. Though this might be that clean in normal HTML. Check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp